# Perfect object to be recognized with OpenCV

Tags: android, iphone, opencv, pattern-matching, object-detection

I have an application where I want to track 2 objects at a time that are rather small in the picture.
This application should be running on Android and iPhone, so the algorithm should be efficient.

For my customer it is perfectly fine if we deliver some patterns along with the software that are attached to the objects to be tracked to have a well-recognizable target.

This means that I can make up a pattern on my own.
As I am not that much into image processing yet, I don't know which objects are easiest to recognize in a picture even if they are rather small.
Color is also possible, although processing several planes separately is not desired because of the generated overhead.

Thank you for any advice!!
Best,

guitarflow

Comment: How robust does it need to be (i.e., target scale and rotation)? Can you have an active target (i.e., light emitting)?

Comment: @mevatron It should be robust as the user is moving around with the camera, but it cannot emit light. I thought of a pattern on a normal sheet of paper which would be viewed from about 3-4 meters in distance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get this straight, your object should:

1. Be printable on an A4
2. Be recognizeable up to 4 meters
3. Rotational invariance is not so important (I'm making the assumption that the user will hold the phone +/- upright)

I recommend printing a large checkboard and using a combination of color-matching and corner detection. Try different combinations to see what's faster and more robust at difference distances.

**Color:** if you only want to work on one channel, you can print in red/green/blue*, and then work only on that respective channel. This will already filter a lot and increase contrast "for free".
   Otherwise, a histogram backprojection is in my experience quite fast. See [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html#histogram-comparison).

Also, let's say you have only 4 squares with RGB+black (see image), it would be easy to get all red contours, then check if it has the correct neighbouring colors: a patch of blue to it's right and a patch of green below it, both of roughly the same area. This alone might be robust enough, and is equivalent to working on 1 channel since for each step you're only accessing one specific channel (search for contours in red, check right in blue, check below in green).

[image: RGB squares]

If you're getting a lot of false-positives, you can then use corners to filter your hits. In the example image, you have 9 corners already, in fact even more if you separate channels, and if it isn't enough you can make a true checkerboard with several squares in order to have more corners. It will probably be sufficient to check how many corners are detected in the ROI in order to reject false-positives, otherwise you can also check that the spacing between detected corners in x and y direction is uniform (i.e. form a grid).

**Corners:** Detecting corners has been greatly explored and there are several methods here. I don't know how efficient each one is, but they are fast enough, and after you've reduced the ROIs based on color, this should not be an issue.
Perhaps the simplest is to simply erode/dilate with a cross to find corners. See [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) .
You'll want to first threshold the image to create a binary map, probably based on color as metnioned above.
Other corner detectors such as Harris detector are well [documented](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html?highlight=harris%20detector).

Oh and I don't recommend using Haar-classifiers. Seems unnecessarily complicated and not so fast (though very robust for complex objects: i.e. if you can't use your own pattern), not to mention the huge amount of work for training.

Comment: hey @lifesayko, thanks for your answer!! Just to make sure I got you right : I would design a checkerboard in A4 size with say six lines in width and four lines in height. Each "quadrant" would get a separate color : left upper quadrant RED, right upper GREEN .... I would get the contours of them in each channel and then find edges in their bounding rectangles. Did I get you right?

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. What you mentioned is definitely also possible. I think the example image I posted is very simple (it's basically the same thing reduced), so I would try that first. If it isn't robust enough, then I would try something like what you said.

Comment: Hey again. I looked into it and I think there is a bit of misunderstanding. With "one channel" I did not mean to process RGB separately. I rather meant that I would like to work on a grayscale image. I think the color stuff is a bit problematic as you don't know what the user's printer is doing with it. So I would prefer to work with a black and white pattern. ( I already marked your answer as the accepted one )

Comment: I see, I thought the reason for not using RGB was computational cost, so I was pointing out that it isn't an issue :). I still think it shouldn't be, even if the printer is a bit off with the colors, it should still be close enough, unless they don't have a color printer...

Still, the same idea can be used with black and white. I would still start with just 4 squares, though it's now more likely that you'll need more to be robust enough.

Answer (score 1):

Haar training is your friend mate.

This tutorial should get you started: http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

Basically you train something called a classifier based on sample images (2000 or so of the object you want to track). OpenCV already has the tools required to build these classifiers and functions in the library to detect objects.

Comment: Ok, this might work. But this seems like a whole lot of work!! Isn't there an easier way if I am ABSOLUTELY FREE to choose the object/pattern to be detected?