# Ideal pattern for opencv detection

Tags: opencv, feature-detection

Well, maybe not "ideal" but "best I can do with simple shapes."

I have an application where I'm using a camera attached to a moving robot actuator and need to detect it's location in the world (using the onboard camera). My research isn't in vision processing so I like like to generate an "easy" pattern to allow for fast and relatively accurate position and rotation detection. The pattern will be printed out and taped to a flat surface (note that this can cause occasional lighting gradients across the paper) and the camera axis will usually be roughly perpendicular.

Consistency of finding the pattern is actually more important than precision of measurement; i.e. I'd rather have something that almost always gives a useful less accurate result than something that gives very accurate and precise results but fails to find anything 10% of the time.

Lastly, this will be used inside of a control loop so speed is quite important.

For all the opencv/vision experts out there, what would be good choices for pattern selection (and associated opencv algorithms) for this?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086380/perfect-object-to-be-recognized-with-opencv/10101171#10101171

Comment: Ah thanks. I tried searching before posting but missed an obvious one I guess.

Comment: No worries. You can upvote the answers you found useful on the other question ;).